# How Do I determine the actual Server For Connecting PHP And SQL Server Locally?

Tags: php, sql-server, apache, xampp

I am running Windows 7, I use XAMPP, I created my database from command line using sql create local ... When opening SQL SERVER Management Studio My server name is (LocalDB)\LocalDB ... Inclduing The brackets... But when I use the server name to connect to the database I get an error message... My connection code is below... I have added my extensions and enabled them in my php.ini file... I need help as to how can I determine which server name can I use as I assume that could be the problem... I have also tried using LocalDB as it is as just the server name but no luck... I use Windows Authentication Method on my SQL Server Management Studio...

```
<?php
if($connectInfo = array("UID"=>"userName", "PWD"=>"password",'Database'=>'localSample')){
echo "Array Set Up" . "<br/>";
}else{
echo "Could Not Set Array";
die();
}

$serverName = "LocalDB";

if($conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectInfo)){
    echo "Good Connection Good... " . "<br/>";
}else{
    echo "Connection Not Good";
    die();
}

?>
```

Comment: The Response I get is connection not good... Which how I would assume that perhaps I am using an incorrect server name

Comment: servername is usually `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Thanks for the response... I tried that but no luck at all...

Comment: Please make sure that you configured the the sql server protocols and enable tcp/ip and that there is no firewall in between. You can test this if you specify tcp/ip in the connection options in management studio. If your problem is authentication, you can try your username and passwort as well with management studio by using sql authentication, Perhaps you can isolate this problem this way - if it's working in management studio, the problem has to be on the php side.

Comment: I tried that and from SQL Server SIDE its all good... So I believe it has to do with either how I have set the server and username variables... When checking my Server name and Username on Management Studio, It is listed as (LocalDb)\LocalDB and my username as User-PC\User ... I have tried using LocalDB and (LocalDB)\LocalDB as server name, also trying my user name as both User-PC\User and only User... But no connection so far from PHP side...

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution... Seems I also needed to download an ODBC Driver for SQL Server.... I found it on the link below... All is good now

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434